# Is it possible for a class to set the value of a variable that it inherited from another class in the parameter of its constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Class `A` contains the protected int `x`. Class `B` extends class `A`. Now what class `B` wants to do is set the value of `x` as a passing argument in its own constructor. When I try to do that, I get the error:

> ""x" is not a non-static data member or base class of class "B"".

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    A()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int x)
        : x(x)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Btw; shadowing variable names, like you do, can easily become confusing (and in this case also leads to the need for a ugly explicit `this->` dereference).

Comment: "\[...] declaring data members protected is usually a design error" — *Bjarne Stroustrup*.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Thank you for that.

Comment: @n.m. Can you elaborate on that? The only reason I declared it 'protected' is so that the subclass has access to it.

Comment: Stroustrup explains it better than I could, just google the phrase. Use protected accessor functions instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "set" it, but not *initialize* it, because it has already been initialized when the base class object gets initialized. You can "set" it like this:

```
B(int x) 
{ 
    this->x = x; // assignment, not initialization
}
```

It would make more sense for one of `A`'s constructors to take care of the initialization of `A::x`:

```
A(int x) : x(x) {}
```

and then use that in `B`:

```
using A::A; // allows B b{42};
```

Comment: Or give A a more suitable constructor.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Indeed. I added a few lines on that.